# Что именно нужно логировать в проекте? Контроллеры? Сервисы? Нужно ли вообще логировать сервисы?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

На данный момент я подключил логгер, но он выглядит приблизительно так во всех методах каждого контроллера и что-то мне подсказывает, что это неправильный подход.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/list")
public String getPlaceList(Model model){

    List<PlaceType> placeTypeList = placeTypeService.getAllPlaceType();
    List<Place> places = placeService.getAllPlaces();
    logger.info("Info messages:");
    logger.error("Error messages:");
    model.addAttribute("placeTypesList", placeTypeList);
    model.addAttribute("places", places);
    return "placelist";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/places")
public String getPlaces(@RequestParam("id") String typeId, Model model) {
    logger.info("Info messages:");
    logger.error("Error messages:");
    PlaceType placeType = placeTypeService.getPlaceTypeById(Long.parseLong(typeId));
    List<Place> places = new ArrayList<Place>(placeType.getPlaces());
    model.addAttribute("places", places);
    return "placesList";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Обычно логируется сам факт вызова метода и параметры, которые были переданы в этот метод и результат выполнения метода, перед возвращением значения. Так же, если метод выполняет некие сложные вычисление, то имеет смысл логировать промежуточные результаты. Всё это идёт как `DEBUG` логи.

Все ошибочные состояния(например catch-блок) идут как `ERROR` логи.

В `INFO` логи должна попадать некая общая информация, например что приложение задеплоилось корректно, что какой-то шаг деплоя выполнился корректно(например конфиги нашлись), а вот содержимое конфигов уже лучше в `DEBUG`, хотя если они не большие, можно и в `INFO` оставить.

Comment: Получается, что эти логи в контроллере ни о чем?

Comment: @Khodan.D. Ну те что вы написали да, в них не содержится 0 информации. Вы должны в логи писать какую-то информацию, по которой потому будет понятно правильно ли работает ваше приложение или же где-то ошибка.

Comment: где можно почитать как это делается ? я не могу понять, что мне делать и что и как логгировать. Во все примерах, только дурацкие две строчки как сделать иморт и создать. Ни одного хорошего туториала. Возможно у вас есть хороший материал, который поможет разобраться?

Comment: @Khodan.D. А мой ответ чем вас не устраивает? Я постарался расписать, что логировать, "как" вы уже умеете, судя по коду.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но мне надо посмотреть код, чтобы понять, что и как делается. Например: я понятия не имею как мне залогировать передаваемые параметры метода или как правильно расставить уровни логирования в том самом методе.